# Rails-bootstrap-markdown Gem: not working on POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, markdown

Ok, I'm not sure if I'm the dumb one or if the [Rails-Bootstrap-Markdown Gem](https://github.com/dannytatom/rails-bootstrap-markdown) just doesn't give enough information on how to correctly use the gem.

The text area shows the markdown buttons and correctly manipulates the text. Also, when I click "Preview," the text displays exactly like I want it ("bold", "italic", etc). But when I go to POST the text, it does not parse the text to HTML.

I've added `data: { provide: 'markdown' } to my form's text area and here are my JS and CSS.SCSS files:

application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
//= require cocoon
//= require local_time
//= require bootstrap-markdown-bundle
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

application.css.scss:

```
*= require jquery-ui
*= require bootstrap-markdown
*= require_tree .
*= require bootstrap-datepicker3
*= require_self
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the use of bootstrap markdown here.

> Simple Markdown editing tools that works!

It is stated as a markdown editing tool, that means it is used to produce markdown output, not html output.

The html tags you saw in preview is just something to simulate the display of value in markdown displayer, not the value itself.

If you want to translate the output(in markdown format) to html, you could consider these gems: [redcarpet](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet) or [kramdown](https://github.com/gettalong/kramdown)